# HDMI input not detected on Debian 10

Tags: debian, nvidia, display, hdmi

I am running Debian 10 Buster on an an hybrid laptop with the following GPUs:

```
$ lspci | grep -E "VGA|3D"
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630   (Mobile)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP106M [GeForce GTX 1060] (rev a1)
```

According to system settings > details the GPU in use is: Intel® UHD Graphics 630 (Coffeelake 3x8 GT2)

I have tried to open the Nvidia X server settings but nothing happens.

I previously used Mint and Ubuntu and had no problems the HDMI was detected automatically.

**EDIT: **
Please note I have seen the question [Debian 10 [Buster]: HDMI Input Not detected](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/580561/debian-10-buster-hdmi-input-not-detected).

I have installed backports but it has not helped. Also please find the following information:

````
$xrandr 
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 381mm x 214mm
   1920x1080    120.00*+  60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93  
   1680x1050     84.94    74.89    69.88    59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     85.00    74.76    70.00    59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     85.02    75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      85.00    60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864     100.00    85.06    85.00    75.00    75.00    70.00    60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      85.00    75.05    60.04    85.00    75.03    70.07    60.00  
   1024x768i     86.96  
   960x720       85.00    75.00    60.00  
   928x696       75.00    60.05  
   896x672       75.05    60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       85.00    75.00    70.00    65.00    60.00    85.14    72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       85.02    74.96    69.88    60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       85.08    74.76    70.06    59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       85.02    75.02    60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       85.09    60.00    85.01    72.81    75.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   720x400       85.04  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98    85.08  
   576x432      100.11    85.15    85.09    75.00    75.00    70.00    60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   640x350       85.08  
   512x384       85.00    75.03    70.07    60.00  
   512x384i      87.06  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   416x312       74.66  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       85.27    72.19    75.12    60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       85.18    72.81    75.00    60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   360x200       85.04  
   320x200       85.27  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
   320x175       85.27 ```  

$ xrandr --listproviders
Providers: number : 1
Provider 0: id: 0x43 cap: 0xf, Source Output, Sink Output, Source Offload, Sink Offload crtcs: 3 outputs: 1 associated providers: 0 name:modesetting

$ lspci -nn | grep VGA

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile) [8086:3e9b]
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GP106M [GeForce GTX 1060] [10de:1c20] (rev a1)


$ aplay -l

**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC1220 Analog [ALC1220 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: ALC1220 Digital [ALC1220 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0


$ lshw -c video
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GP106M [GeForce GTX 1060]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:142 memory:a3000000-a3ffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff memory:a0000000-a1ffffff ioport:4000(size=128) memory:a4000000-a407ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:125 memory:a2000000-a2ffffff memory:80000000-8fffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
````

I have as well tried to add backports to the source.list.d file but it has not helped as suggested in the answer given by @telcoM in the aforementioned question.

I have tried the command

```
$ vga_switcheroo
```

but it seems to not be installed in my kernel as it says command not found.

Any other suggestion of how I can solve this problem are welcomed. Thanks!

Comment: Related: [unix.stackexchange.com/questions/580561](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/580561)

Comment: Thanks @Freddy I had seen this but it has not helped me. I am updating/editing my question to reflect this attempt.